# Increasing the efficiency of equipment using Amazon Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning

The problem statement is kind of vague but i am looking for directions because of privacy policy i can't share exact details. so please help out.

We have a problem at hand where we need to increase the efficiency of equipment or in other words decide on which values across multiple parameters should the machines operate to produce optimal outputs.

My query is whether it is possible to come up with such numbers using Linear Regression or Multinomial Logistic Regression algorithms, if no then can you please specify which algorithms will be more suitable. Also can you please point me to some active research done on this kind of problem that is available in public domain.

Does the type of problem i am asking suggestions for comes in the area of Machine Learning ?

Answer (score 2):

Lots of unknowns here but I’ll make some assumptions.

What you are attempting to do could probably be achieved with multiple linear regression. I have zero familiarity with the Amazon service (I didn’t even know it existed until you brought this up, it’s not available in Europe). However, a read of the documentation suggests that the Amazon service would be capable of doing this for you. The problem you will perhaps have is that it’s geared to people unfamiliar with this field and a lot of its functionality might be removed or clumped together to prevent confusion. I am under the impression that you have turned to this service because you too are somewhat unfamiliar with this field.

Something that may suit your needs better is Response Surface Methodology (RSM), which I have applied to industrial optimisation problems that I think are similar to what you suggest. RSM works best if you can obtain your data through an experimental design such as a Central Composite Design or Box-Behnken design. I suggest you spend some time Googling these terms to get your head around them, I don’t think it’s an unmanageable burden to learn how to apply these with no prior experience in this area. Because your question is vague, only you can determine if this really is suitable. If you already have the data in an unstructured format, you can still generate an RSM but it is less robust. There are plenty of open-access articles using these techniques but Science Direct is conveniently down at the moment!

Minitab is a software package that will do all the regression and RSM for you. Its strength is that it has a robust GUI and partially reflects Excel so it is far less daunting to get into than something like R. It also has plenty of guides online. They offer a 30 day free trial so it might be worth doing some background reading, collecting the tutorials you need and develop a plan of action before downloading the trial.

Hope that is some help.

Comment: if you can provide me your email id then i can follow up this on you in greater details, if you are uncomfortable sharing your id publicly , then drop me a mail at subham.bca@gmail.com. Thanks , with your answer i have somewhere to start from

Comment: @SubhamTripathi glad it helped start you off. I am reluctant of being drawn into a one-to-one on this matter for 2 reasons. 1) It's a broad question about a new service, so further info might be of interest to many other people in the future and 2) I do this stuff day in, day out for my own work and risk getting involved in another specific problem. However, if you have any further specific questions, I will do my best to update my answer accordingly or provide an additional answer if necessary. It also allows other people to contribute where I might have model biases or knowledge gaps.